# React-native with Api Handling

Tags: react-native

I'm using react-native ,Now my requirement is that
- I want to use API (POST/GET) : https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2
-But how can i use this url with http request in react-native ?
-How to add parameter like source lang and destination lang or API key etc

Note : I have seen Google Cloud Translation documentation , but i didn;t understand the methods and everything
What's the best solution for my problem ?

Comment: Take a look at [Networking in React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html)

Comment: You can even use `axios` package for making api requests. Also other parameters can be added as a `post data` object or can be specified in the headers. Check their documentation

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example for performing a POST request with parameters using axios library,

```
axios.post('put your url in here', {
    param: 'add your param'
  })
  .then(function (res) {
    console.log(res);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

if you want more refer [this](https://github.com/axios/axios).